# Variables creation before or after Data cleaning?

Tags: sas, normalization, k-means, data-cleaning, skew

I am trying to perform k-means cluster analysis on a dataset with 20 variables and 9000 observations. I want to create 2 new variables (Usage and Payment Ratio) using 4 (Balance, Due date, Payment, Minimum Payment) of the 20 variables in the dataset. Ex: Usage = (Balance/Due date) and Payment_ratio = (payment/minimum payment). Now, should I make these variables at the start itself, or should I first cap the outliers, remove/impute missing values and then create these 2 new variables?

I tried to first clean the data and then created these two variables. Then I also capped the outliers and treated missing values again for these 2 variables. After doing this, these 2 new variables are skewed and I tried taking log, sqrt etc but the variables are still not normal i.e there is still skewness in these variables. After this step, I need to do the Factor Analysis but I cannot proceed.

Can anyone please suggest a way to go about this? Thanks.

Comment: Is minimum payment calculated from payment? Is due date a date or a number of dates? Why do you expect your new variables to be normally distributed?

Comment: No. payment and minimum payment are 2 separate variables, which are already available. Every variable in the data is numeric.The date variable is actually the date of any month (between 1 to 31) and is a 2 digit numeric variable.  If the distribution is symmetric, the typical value is unambiguous. Isn't it? This is my point of view as I'm at the initial stages of learning.

Comment: Still not sure I understand the meaning of `Due date`. Is it the experiation date of some kind of depth in days?
_PS: Dates and numbers are both numeric, what SAS is concerned._

Comment: Hi Dirk, it would be safe to say that date variable is a numeric variable which is easily divisible by balance variable to create usage variable. I’m concerned if I should create these variables at the beginning or after cleaning the data. In my analysis, I have created them after data cleaning ( outliers treatment, missinh values treatment) and the variables are highly skewed. Is it okay to proceed with Factor Analysis without transforming these two variables? If not, what would be the best way to minimize the skewness?

Comment: Please be correct in your language: you don't devide by balance, you devide by Due Date, for example.

Comment: Sounds like a statistics question, not a programming question.  Not sure what you mean by cleaning, but if it involves non-linear transformations then will definitely want to make your variables before transforming them.

Comment: I agree with @Tom, this question is better suited to Cross Validated.